# Wake Lock does not dim screen

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I am writing an Android app, and would like to have my screen dim after acquiring a wake lock. However, my screen does not dim. It just continues (does not crash) as if nothing happened. I know the wake lock IS begin set because of some test code not shown here. The following is my code:

```
//Relevant declarations:
    PowerManager.WakeLock w1;
    PowerManager pm;

public void onClick(View view) {
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService((Context.POWER_SERVICE));
w1 = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK), "My Tag");
w1.acquire(); //DOES NOT DIM
}

public void onShake () {
if (w1.isHeld())
{
w1.release();
}

//Manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
w1.acquire(); //DOES NOT DIM
```

If you are expecting it to immediately dim, that is not how it works. `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` does mean "change the current brightness to dim". It means "we need the screen to be *at least* dim". Anything else, such as using the device, can cause the screen to go to full brightness.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Just had to be patient and wait some time before finally went dim. Shaking it released the wake lock, and immediately brightened the screen again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: I did do that. Forgot to mention it.